# Keep birthday public, but don't allow reminder notification

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to have my birthday set to Public so everyone can check that on my profile but my friends won't get the birthday reminder?

Answer (score 1):

**No**. As of now it is not possible. Changing the privacy setting for date and month to "Only me" will not notify to your friends.

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible, at all. The reminder must be visible either :by  you, public....

Comment: This doesn't add much to the other answer.